# What is the fastest way to level up Palicoes?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

In Monster Hunter Generations, Palicoes can level up to a staggering maximum of 50, when the highest levelled newly hired Palicoes that I can find are level 20. What is the fastest way to complete this long journey?

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 main ways to level up Palicos:

1. Take them with you on quests
2. Play as them in Prowler mode
3. Intense Training through Neko or your Housekeeper
4. Set them to train through the Palico Board

Taking them with you is dependant on many factors(like rank, monster, how many times they faint, etc), and it is probably the slowest method of the 4 next to basic training (palico food skill helps a lot, but still much weaker than the other methods)

Playing as the Prowler does get them more exp than taking them as partners, and it can get some prowler quests out of the way. Again, this method is still pretty slow and dependant on what you do, don't expect a lot of levels for gathering quests.

Intense Training is probably the best method, but it does require you to remember to check up and them when they finish, let them catnap to recover all the enthusiasm intense training burns, and then train them again. It also allows for special items to boost the exp gain even further.

The next best thing would be training through the palico board. This method let's them train indefinitely, without you having to watch over and change their status. This method also allows up to 5 trainees, where intense only allows 3. Basic training is a much slower rate than intense, but again. you don't need to take care of them like you do with Intense.

All in all, I'd say **Intense Training** would be your best bet, just remember to check up on them, catnap, and reset the training at the correct times.

Comment: It seems this answer is more about the most convenient way to level up Palicoes, rather than the absolute fastest. I'd also like to see some numbers rather than observations if possible.

Comment: I can second Intense Training, from experience my Palicos that goes through cycles of intense training and rest can reach lvl 35 from 10 when those I bring as partners for quest only reach ~31 from 10 during the same period - however I did an assortment of quests between Hunting and Gathering thus exp for Partner Palicos might not be optimal. And I'd like to add that if they are put into intense training they'd be unavailable for other productive activities such as Trading or Meownster Hunting.